# Angular Behaviour Subject callback 'this' is undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a BehaviourSubject like this:

```
subject: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
```

Then in the ngAfterViewInit, I want to subscribe to it like this:

```
this.subject.pipe(debounceTime(500), distinctUntilChanged(),
tap(() => 
   this.someCallbackFunction())
).subscribe();
```

Callback function where I can't access this.whatever:

```
someCallbackFunction(): void {
    // I can't access the component level members because they are undefined.
}
```

How can I solve this?

Edit, whole component example:

```
export class MyComponent implements  AfterViewInit {

  subject: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
  someOtherObject: any; // this one is assigned else where, trust me

  constructor() { }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.subject.pipe(
        debounceTime(500),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        tap(() => this.callbackFunction()))
        .subscribe();
  }


  callbackFunction(): void {
      console.log(this.someOtherObject); // undefined
  }

}
```

Comment: are you sure it is  `this.someCallbackFunction()` and not  `this.someCallbackFunction` ??? (note missing ())

Comment: Yes, i tried with tap( () => this.someCallbackFunction() ) and also with tap(this.someCallbackFunction.bind(this))

Comment: And this issue only comes with BehaviourSubject, Event Emitter works properly, sadly I need behavious subject here.

Comment: `()=>this.callback()` must work and `(this.callback.bind(this))` would woirk.

Comment: Could you show more code? maybe the whole component? Is that `this.subject..` line inside a function perhaps?

Comment: Added an example component.

Comment: Yea the "trust me" part seems suspicious :-) otherwise it should work. We need to see more code about how those members are being assigned. Probably an async race condition or you're not using the same instances of a service. Also where are you importing the `BehaviourSubject` from?

Comment: `  someOtherObject: any; // this one is assigned else where, trust me` that is so funny of you tbh. What exactly is the error? that you cannot read `someOtherObject` of undefined or console.log prints `undefined`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must know that `BehaviorSubject` wil emmit value to any subscriber at subscription time. In your case simply speaking, your subscription callback fires before required field is set by whatever is supposed to set it

```
  someOtherObject: any; // this one is assigned else where, trust me
```

this is bold claim to be honest.

Consider that:

`console.log(this.someOtherObject);` this will yeld `undefined` to the console while

`console.log((undefined as any).someOtherObject)` would yeld an exception. If you are seeing `undefined` in the console, then the whole question is based of wrong (yours) assumptions.

You said that you are "confirming" the state with `console.log(this)` and you "see everything". This is not reliable way due to how console works (I know because I did the exact same mistakes in the past). Try to do `console.log(JSON.stringify(this))` so you will see the difference.